# Prevent GNU Screen from closing

Tags: gnu-screen

Is there any way to make GNU Screen not close if I end all its subprocesses?  Ideally, it would create a new window running a shell if I accidentally closed the last window.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're using bash and accidentally closes the shell with Ctrl-D, you can

```
export IGNOREEOF=1
```

This will give you a warning and require you to press Ctrl-D twice, or type exit instead.

Comment: Thanks! I added this to my `~/.screenrc`:

`setenv IGNOREEOF 10`
/
`screen -t main bash`
/
`unsetenv IGNOREEOF`

Comment: +1 because there's no part of my life that hasn't been improved after learning that!

Comment: I did some more investigation and if you search for "Suddenly the Dungeon collapses!!" in attacher.c, it should be possible to change the code to spawn a new window somehow, instead of shutting down the whole thing. The source is just one quick git clone away: git://git.sv.gnu.org/screen.git

Comment: Haha!  I don't really want to go to the effort of maintaining my own patch to Screen, but thanks for  reminding me of the Nethack option.  (Though I was more of an Angband man myself...)

Comment: Accidental terminal cloures was a huge annoyance for me. Added `set -o ignoreeof` to ~/.bashrc; works in konsole | xfce4-terminal | ...

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a way to do that specifically, but I find `zombie {}` useful; when I close a window, it prompts me to hit `{` or `}` to close or reopen it, respectively.

Comment: can this be used without having a screenrc?